# Yii Php : Hiding or showing column based on data value

Tags: gridview, yii

I'm developing in **Yii** and im currently using Yii **twitter bootstrap** used to display some columns in a **GridView**:

Suppose I have this :

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
    'id'=>'gridview',
    'dataProvider'=>new CArrayDataProvider($model),
    'template'=>"{items}",
    'type'=>'bordered',
    'columns'=>array(
                array(
                    'header' => 'Entries',
                    'value' => '$data->entry_name'
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'value',
                    'header' => 'Value',
                    'value'=>function($data){
                        //if $data->value is zero then hide the "Value" column
                        if($data->value == 0){
                        //do something to hide the column here
                        }
                        //otherwise return a label to display the value inside
                        return CHtml::label($data->value,FALSE,array('id'=>'label'));
                    },
                    'type'=>'raw',
                ),
              )
      )
);
```

I could hide the entire column by using:

```
'headerHtmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'display:none'), 
'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'display:none'),
```

But this is after i passed the columns parameter to the widget. I want to hide the "Value" column when its value is zero. How do i do **hide or show** the entire column **based on its value?** Thank You very much!

Comment: The column as a whole has many values, not just one. Can you be more specific?

Comment: As Jon already commented, a column is a collection of values. Your question is how to hide the entire column based on it's value, which doesn't really make sense because a column has many values.

Comment: it actually makes sense..for example, you have a set of values and i know that there are a collection of values, but you have a value that is unacceptable that you need to hide the entire column because of that value. for example: all rows in that "value" column contain all 1's , but then a single row is actually zero. and then you decide to hide it. (i have a use for this)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
array(
    'name' => 'value',
    'header' => 'Value',
    'value' => '$data->value',
    'visible' => '$data->value != 0',
    'type' => 'raw',
)
```

Comment: API Reference [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridColumn#visible-detail).

Comment: Will this hide it on the client only? or is there a chance someone could get the hands on that data without hacking the server?